# Calling a function in a loop of another function

Tags: python, while-loop, calling-convention

**Background** - I have a function that takes an API response (`api_response`) from another function (`api_response = api_call()`). `Code Block #1` continues to iterate until `meta` is in the response. Once `meta` is in `api_response` then `Code Block #2` will return `api_response`.

**Issue** - whilst my code is testing `api_response` for `meta`, I haven't found a way to include continuously calling the other function (`api_response = api_call()` in my `while loop`, which will allow determination as to when `meta` is still in `api_response`.

**Function** -

```
def unpack_response():
    # Code Block # 1
    api_response = api_call()
    while "meta" not in api_response:
        id_value = "id"
        res1 = [val[id_value] for key, val in api_response.items() if id_value in val]
        id_value = "".join(res1)
        percent_value = "percent_complete"
        res2 = (tuple(api_response["data"]["attributes"].get("percent_complete", '') for key, val in api_response.items()))
        print(f' Your data requested, associated with ID: {id_value} is {res2} complete!')
    # Code Block # 2
    if "meta" in api_response:
        return api_response
unpack_response()
```

**Question** - does anyone have any pointers, as to how I might integrate `api_response` into my loop, so it keeps being called every loop iteration?

Comment: Put the call into the loop, use `else`, and your function doesn't return anything

Comment: Use a walrus operator

Comment: Thanks @MadPhysicist - I have corrected the function to `return api_response`. Inc. the call within the loop makes sense (thank you). However where does `else` come into play?

Comment: `if not x: ...` followed by `if x: ...` is usually better phrased as `if not x: ... else: ...`.

Comment: Thanks, I have changed my `function` appropriately. I am still a little confused where in the function I include `api_response = api_call()` in the loop. I get `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'api_response = api_call()' referenced before assignment` error when placing after `if "meta" not in api_response:`. Should it be before the `if` statement and in the loop itself?

Comment: Let my know if my answer makes things clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of options here. If you have python 3.8+, you can use the [walrus operator (`:=`)](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions) to put `api_call` directly in the condition of the loop:

```
def unpack_response():
    while "meta" not in (api_response := api_call()):
        id_value = "id"
        res1 = [val[id_value] for key, val in api_response.items() if id_value in val]
        id_value = "".join(res1)
        percent_value = "percent_complete"
        res2 = (tuple(api_response["data"]["attributes"].get("percent_complete", '') for key, val in api_response.items()))
        print(f' Your data requested, associated with ID: {id_value} is {res2} complete!')
    return api_response
```

A more traditional, but no less idiomatic method is to run the loop forever and `break` when the correct condition is reached:

```
def unpack_response():
    while True:
        api_response = api_call()
        if "meta" in api_response:
            return api_response
        id_value = "id"
        res1 = [val[id_value] for key, val in api_response.items() if id_value in val]
        id_value = "".join(res1)
        percent_value = "percent_complete"
        res2 = (tuple(api_response["data"]["attributes"].get("percent_complete", '') for key, val in api_response.items()))
        print(f' Your data requested, associated with ID: {id_value} is {res2} complete!')
```

In both cases, you might consider slowing down the rate at which you make API calls with a sleep or similar.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if I get this correctly.
Could you just do this?

```
def unpack_response():
    # Code Block # 1
    while True:
        api_response = api_call()
        if "meta" not in api_response:
            id_value = "id"
            res1 = [val[id_value] for key, val in api_response.items() if id_value in val]
            id_value = "".join(res1)
            percent_value = "percent_complete"
            res2 = (api_response["data"]["attributes"].get("percent_complete", '') for key, val in api_response.items())
            print(f' Your data requested, associated with ID: {id_value} is {percent_value} complete!')
            time.sleep(5)
        # Code Block #2
        else:
            print(api_response)
            break
```

Comment: The call is clearly not in the loop here...

Comment: I simply realized that I pasted a wrong script ;)

Comment: Now your code is improperly indented

Comment: Why are you suggesting a 5-second sleep?

Comment: sleep was in the original question, but it was edited out.